# Why does this bronze color look so wrong?

Tags: color, perception

I'm making a site where you can earn badges: bronze, silver and gold. The bronze color doesn't seem right.

[image: #1 Visual Aid]

**Bronze:** `#B9600D`

**Silver:** `#C0C0C0`

**Gold:** `#FACC34`

Does it look weird to anyone else? Or, just me?

Comment: Hello Code Play and welcome. Can you please edit your question to meet our [critique requirements](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/682)? As is, your question is a bit opinion based

Comment: @ZachSaucier How should I have phrased this question? Like: Is the bronze color too dark? I'm sorry, this is my first question...

Comment: http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/681/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work/682#682

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your other colours are a lot brighter than the bronze, which looks a little brown to me.

Try out #cd7f32 instead for a lighter look across the board.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks a bit too brown to my eye. Google used these colours for their search graphics during the 2012 London Olympics:

[image: Google gold/silver/bronze]

- Gold: #ffce00
- Silver: #b5b6b5
- Bronze: #b67d00